# git unable to merge my local branch with remote

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control

I cloned a git repo of my org like below

> **git clone https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks**

It asked for my username/password and successfully cloned it.

And then I checked out a new local branch

> **git checkout -b patchv1**

I made a couple of commits.

then I checkout to **master** and merged my **patchv1** branch with *local* **master**.

> **git checkout master**
>
> **git pull**
>
> **git merge patchv1**

Below is my git status output

> **git status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

> **git remote show origin**

```
* remote origin   
Fetch URL: https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks.git   
Push  URL: https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks.git   
HEAD branch: master 
Remote branches:
   upgrade-schedules           tracked
   ...................           .....
   patchv2                     tracked   
Local branch configured for 'git pull':
  master merges with remote master   
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

I want to push my *local* **master** branch to remote origin, but with a different name. So, I use below command with -u so that the remote branch gets created

> **git push -u origin master:newpatchv2**

Got below error

```
remote: Permission to my_org_name/runbooks.git denied to my_username. fatal:
unable to access 'https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks.git/': The
requested URL returned error: 403
```

From the webUI, I tried to edit a file in master branch of remote repo and got below error,

```
"You’re editing a file in a project you don’t have write access to. 
Submitting a change to this file will write it to a new branch in your fork **my_username/runbooks**, so you can send a pull request."
```

I read further about this and found the below statement

**Changes made to the forked repository can be merged with the original repository via a pull request. Pull request knocks the repository owner and tell that “I have made some changes, please merge these changes to your repository if you like it”. On the other hand, changes made on the local machine (cloned repository) can be pushed to the upstream repository directly. For this, the user must have the write access for the repository otherwise this is not possible. If the user does not have the write access, the only way to go is through the forked request. So in that case, the changes made in the cloned repository are first pushed to the forked repository and then a pull request is created.**

So, I went to my org's github webui repo page (url - https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks) and clicked on fork. It said,

`"You've already forked runbooks"` and showed me the below repo

**my_username/runbooks**

Now, as per the statement what I read, I can push my changes to my *forked repo* **my_username/runbooks** and then create a pull request. Right? But in my org's github webui runbooks repo page, If I click on "**New Pull Request**"

Under "**Compare Changes**", I see like below

```
base: master   <---  compare: <drop_down>
```

when I click on the drop_down I don't find **my_username/runbooks** repo at all.

**Two questions:**

1. How to push my local master branch to my forked repo - **my_username/runbooks** ? Should I need to change my remote origin somehow since I cannot create a new remote branch in my org's repo?

   The url to my forked repo is like below

   [https://giturl/my_username/runbooks?organization=my_username&organization=my_username](https://myorgurl/myusername/runbooks?organization=myusername&organization=myusername)
2. Once I push my local master to my forked repo - **my_username/runbooks**,
   how to create a pull request in my **my_org_name/runbooks** repo as **my_username/runbooks** is not being listed either in the *base* or in the *compare* of "**Compare Changes**" page.

Sorry if the question is very basic. But I have a hard time understanding this and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro tip: never change the `master` branch on a fork of a repo, or any branch that came from upstream.  Your master branch will diverge from upstream and you won't be able to pull  upstream into the local branch.

In your workflow, what would have made more sense is before making your commits, create a new local branch, `git checkout -b newpatchv2`, and commit to that.  Push `newpatchv2` to your fork, and then create a PR in the *upstream* repo to request they pull in your changes.  They may not accept the PR as is, and if your changes are already in your *master* branch, you won't be able to sync back up with the remote master, having diverged history by pushing changes into your local master that aren't (yet) in upstream and may not ever be (pending PR approval).  Remember, git is a *distributed* change control system, and other contributors' PRs may get into upstream master before your own.

If you do end up diverging your local master branch, the easiest fix is to branch off your local master to a new branch (say old-master), then delete your local master branch and pull remote master back down.  Once you're in sync with master, keep it that way - branch *offf* master to make changes, then pull those changes back *into* master only when they've been merged to upstream master.

Now let's get to your questions.

> How to push my local master branch to my forked repo - my_username/runbooks ? Should I need to change my remote origin somehow since I cannot create a new remote branch in my org's repo?

Since `git` is a *distributed* version control system, having multiple remotes is perfectly fine.  In this case, you might even have 3 remotes - your organization's remote, your personal fork, and the upstream remote from which the org forked.  The only special thing about the `origin` upstream is that if you clone a repo, it automatically creates a remote source in the local repo, and calls it `origin`.
You can add more origins:

`git remote add myfork https://github.com/.../..`

Then you can `git push myfork` instead of `git push origin`.  Note there I'm not specifying a branch.  Keep things simple!  Until you consider yourself a git adept, branch *before* committing and keep the remote branch the same as your local branch.

> Once I push my local master to my forked repo - my_username/runbooks, how to create a pull request in my my_org_name/runbooks repo as my_username/runbooks is not being listed either in the base or in the compare of "Compare Changes" page.

There is a "compare across forks" button that should allow you to select a different fork for the destination of your PR.  See this doc from github for screenshots of what that looks like:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork

Comment: I think I screwed up big time. I ran "git checkout -b old_master". Then I deleted my master branch by running "git branch -D master". Now I was trying to git pull. But I was getting message stating it's already up-to-date, "$ git pull origin master
From https://giturl/my_org_name/runbooks
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

But I couldn't see any master branch. So, i checked out empty branch by "git checkout --orphan master". I then thought I'll delete the files in this branch and ran "rm -rf *". Notwall my branches are listing all files with D beside it

Comment: I though deleting files by running "rm -rf" in the branch will only delete this branch. But now, all my branches are listing files with "D" beside it when I am checking out. Also, I am not able to see any files. Is there anyway I can recover it?

Comment: File deletion is an operation that can be tracked by github, so those deletions are now unstaged, uncommitted changes, exactly the same as if you edited a file.  You're guessing, and that only leads to confusion.   Slow down and take the time to experiment and understand what you're doing.  Use `git diff` to see the differences between branches.  Your `old_master` branch should have the commits you are looking for, so try `git diff old_master` to see your changes.  Git is too complex to guess your way through it.  It usually takes folks at least a few months of consistent usage to runderstand

Comment: I was able to retrieve it. It's all good now. Now "git branch" shows only one branch which is the old_master and it has my changes. Now, how to pull remote repo and make it as my master branch? 

I tried this command  - " git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master", 

but got error,

"fatal: branch 'master' does not exist"

Appreciate your help.